# iOS Music Library: How to tell if a given Playlist is a folder

Tags: ios, swift, mpmediaquery, mpmediaitemcollection

Say I have an iOS music library with this playlist structure:

```
A Folder
|
---> A Playlist
     |
     ---> Song A
```

I run the following code:

```
import MediaPlayer

let playlists = MPMediaQuery.playlists().collections! as! [MPMediaPlaylist]
for playlist in playlists {
    let firstItemName = playlist.items.first?.title ?? "none"
    print("playlist: \(playlist.name!), first item: \"\(firstItemName)\"")
}
```

and I get this console output:

> playlist: A Playlist, first item: "Song A"
>
> playlist: A Folder, first item: "Song A"

I've looked through all of the MediaPlayer framework documentation, and can't find any way to discover the parent/child relationship between the playlist and the folder through the API (or even to tell that a collection contains other collections). I'd like to present A Playlist only after a user has browsed through A Folder, rather than showing them as siblings (or maybe even filter out A Folder altogether.

Also, the folder and the playlist both have the same class at runtime: `MPConcreteMediaPlaylist`.

Comment: Hi Dov, have u figured it out?